# how to align an image to the center of the div?

Tags: css

I am trying to align an image in a div to center. I have tried the following but its not working. Please tell me how to fix this . thanks in advance.

```
<div class="erabox"><img src="indicator2.gif" alt="1910 to 1919" width="229" height="38" /></div>
```

Comment: what is the code of class `erabox`?

Comment: where is your class `erabox` codes??

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="erabox" style="text-align:center"><img src="indicator2.gif" alt="1910 to 1919" width="229" height="38" /></div>
```

just you need `style="text-align:center"` in your div tag.

Comment: only text-align center wont work. you should also give margin or padding from left or right then you ll get your image in center.

Comment: @Pro.. why do we need to use `margin` or `padding`? I think `text-align:center` is perfect for horizontally center the `<img>`.

Comment: @VinothKumar Dear Vinoth you must put the code of your class `erabox` if you want to get 100% perfect solution.

Comment: ya it came center.. but it should come in middle.. left,right is ok nw.. that same thing is needed in top nad botttom

Comment: @Vinoth through your css image will come in center only from horizontal. Not from vertical. So if that div has border, than it doesn't seem image in middle of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following CSS code. It makes your `<img>` aligned center horizontally and aligned middle vertically.

```
.erabox{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use margin auto:

```
  .erabox img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/apiwox/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in CSS. it will work for sure 
    align="absmiddle"

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.erabox{
    position:relative;
}

.erabox img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-19px; /* Half of images height */
    margin-left:-115px; /* Half of images width */
}
```

Comment: plz try This code                                                       <div class="erabox" style='width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid blue;align:absmiddle'>
<img src="indicator2.gif" style='width:100px;border:1px solid red;align:absmiddle;align:absmiddle' alt="1910 to 1919" width="229" height="38" /></div>

<style>
.erabox{
    text-align:center;
}

</style>

Comment: Absolute positioning will remove the image from the flow of the content of the document. That might be an overkill for a simple horizontal centering task like this.

Comment: I supposed that parent div's height and width are known because image is aligned not only horizontally but also vertically. My solution is alternative of 'display:table-cell' that doesn't work in ie7

Answer (score 0):

If .erabox div's width and height are fixed or at least it's height and width are always surely greater than image's you can use image as a background

HTML

```
<div class="erabox"></div>
```

CSS

```
.erabox{
    background:url("indicator2.gif") no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
```